# Regex for matching [^whatever-here] and restricting \[^...]

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match some part from a text which is something like:

> This is dummy text, and file added is **[^file.pdf]** and this is my format **\\[^myfile.png]**

First `[^...]` is what I want to match (it's a file link actually), and if user types this format manually in the input, it will be escaped as you can see second `\\[^...]`. So I want to get the text between all the `[^...]`'s and don't match if it has `\` with the bracket.

I have tried `[^\\]\[.*\]$`, but it is not working. Also tried `(?!.*?[\\])\[.*\]`, this one matches the brackets but doesn't restrict the bracket with slash.

*I am using PYTHON (3.9.*) and please note I am getting this text format from the API, so changing the text format is not the solution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a negated character class, `[^\\]`, that *requires* a char other than `\` in front of your expected matches, this excluded matches at the start of string. Another issue is using a greedy dot, `.*`. It matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as *many* as possible, so you matched from the first `[` till the last `]`. You did not specify that there must be `^` after the `[`, that also caused matching string with no `^` after `[`.

You can use

```py
(?<!\\)(\[\^[^][]*])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HnGvY0/5). *Details*:

- `(?<!\\)` - negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `\` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\[\^` - `[^` substring
- `[^][]*` - a negated character class that matches any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Hey! somehow I need to setup this in NodeJS now, but it's not working in NodeJS, and I think look-behind is the culprit. Can you change it send here in comment?

Comment: Check the demo you added and shift from python to JS

Comment: @U-Dev Of course, escape the `]` inside the character class, `/(?<!\\)(\[\^[^\][]*])/g`